# Override a "private" method in a python module

Tags: python, testing, mocking, overriding, private

I want to test a function in python, but it relies on a module-level "private" function, that I don't want called, but I'm having trouble overriding/mocking it. Scenario:

module.py

```
_cmd(command, args):
  # do something nasty

function_to_be_tested():
  # do cool things
  _cmd('rm', '-rf /')
  return 1
```

test_module.py

```
import module
test_function():
  assert module.function_to_be_tested() == 1
```

Ideally, in this test I dont want to call _cmd. I've looked at some other threads, and I've tried the following with no luck:

```
 test_function():
   def _cmd(command, args):
     # do nothing
     pass
   module._cmd = _cmd
```

although checking module._cmd against _cmd doesn't give the correct reference. Using mock:

```
from mock import patch

def _cmd_mock(command, args):
  # do nothing
  pass

@patch('module._cmd', _cmd_mock) 
test_function():
   ...
```

gives the correct reference when checking module._cmd, although `function_to_be_tested' still uses the original _cmd (as evidenced by it doing nasty things).

This is tricky because _cmd is a module-level function, and I dont want to move it into a module

Comment: Works fine for me. Is this your actual code?

Comment: More-or-less: the structure is the same, did you try 
module._cmd = _cmd 
or the patch?

Comment: How did you import module? Can you give us, how is it actually written? Because it's working fine for me.

Comment: The patch. https://gist.github.com/matsjoyce/07f652d6cf4b3e548a13

Comment: Hmm. Weird. I am using twisted.trial.unittest, and there are some deferreds being passed around. Could it be twisted mucking with my references?

Comment: Well, try taking twisted out an see if thats the problem. Otherwise, post the code that actually has a problem.

Comment: @OverlordAlex Is `_cmd` hooked by some decorator in your production module code? If it is the case you should post the real example because decorators can change scenario.

Comment: It looks like the function to be tested is *not* using the global reference to call that function... You didn't post a sufficient example to display your problem. Until you don't update it nobody can really answer except with guessing in how that reference is obtained.

Comment: I took twisted out, still had the problem. However, @Bakuriu pointed me to the correct solution. 

The problem was with the way the code is structured: _cmd is a module-level function, while the function resides in a class defined in that same module. When I overrided the function in the module, for some reason the method used its own old reference to the function.

Solution: Make a reference to the entire module. Assign the _cmd in this reference to the _cmd_mock, and then specifically call function_to_be_mocked from this local reference.

(sorry about late response, we had a 4 day weekend)

Comment: @OverlordAlex Maybe in the class where the function to test reside `_cmd` is assigned to a static attribute of class and your class use its static reference to call `_cmd`. If it is the case you should patch the reference in the class instead of module's one.

Answer (score 2):

**[Disclaimer]**

The synthetic example posted in this question works and the described issue become from specific implementation in production code. Maybe this question should be closed as off topic because the issue is not reproducible.

---

**[Note]** For impatient people *Solution* is at the end of the answer.

---

Anyway that question given to me a good point to thought: how we can patch a method reference when we cannot access to the *variable* where the reference is?

Lot of times I found some issue like this. There are lot of ways to meet that case and the commons are

- Decorators: the instance we would like replace is passed as decorator argument or used in decorator static implementation
- What we would like to patch is a default argument of a method

In both cases maybe refactor the code is the best way to play with that but what about if we are playing with some legacy code or the decorator is a third part decorator?

Ok, we have the back on the wall but we are using python and in python nothing is impossible. What we need is just the reference of the function/method to patch and instead of patching its reference we can patch the `__code__`: yes I'm speaking about patching the bytecode instead the function.

Get a real example. I'm using default parameter case that is simple, but it works either in decorator case.

```
def cmd(a):
    print("ORIG {}".format(a))
def cmd_fake(a):
    print("NEW {}".format(a))
def do_work(a, c=cmd):
    c(a)

do_work("a")
cmd=cmd_fake
do_work("b")
```

Output:

> ```
> ORIG a
> ORIG b
> ```

Ok In this case we can test `do_work` by passing `cmd_fake` but there some cases where is impossible do it: for instance what about if we need to call something like that:

```
def what_the_hell():
    list(map(lambda a:do_work(a), ["c","d"]))
```

what we can do is patch `cmd.__code__` instead of `_cmd` by

```
cmd.__code__ = cmd_fake.__code__
```

So follow code

```
do_work("a")
what_the_hell()
cmd.__code__ = cmd_fake.__code__
do_work("b")
what_the_hell()
```

Give follow output:

> ```
> ORIG a
> ORIG c
> ORIG d
> NEW b
> NEW c
> NEW d
> ```

Moreover if we want to use a mock we can do it by add follow lines:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, call
cmd_mock = Mock()
def cmd_mocker(a):
    cmd_mock(a)

cmd.__code__=cmd_mocker.__code__
what_the_hell()
cmd_mock.assert_has_calls([call("c"),call("d")])
print("WORKS")
```

That print out

> ```
> WORKS
> ```

---

Maybe I'm done... but OP still wait for a *solution* of his *issue*

```
from mock import patch, Mock

cmd_mock = Mock()
#A closure for grabbing the right function code
def cmd_mocker(a):
    cmd_mock(a)

@patch.object(module._cmd,'__code__', new=cmd_mocker.__code__) 
test_function():
   ...
```

Now I should say **never use this trick unless you are with the back on the wall**. Test should be simple to understand and to debug ... try to debug something like this and you will become mad!

Comment: Great comment! Unfortunately it was my stuff-up by not providing a more complete working example. The problem was with the way the code was structured - I'm still not 100% sure why the default solution doesn't work, but I've got enough for a work-around.

EDIT: how does one go about closing a question due to the askers mistake?

Comment: @OverlordAlex you can just delete it .... or edit to cover better your real case. There are some bias on my comment :)... I really love my answer because embrace the dark side of the code. In the case you would delete the question let me know that I'll copy my answer. Anyway my answer give a *ready to use simple and general solution* to solve every case where you don't really know where to patch because the real reference is shadowed somewhere in the code.